# Pulling blog data on any page in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

So I know how to show recent blogs using

```
---

blog:

  recent_posts:

    limit: {{theme_settings.homepage_blog_posts_count}}

---

 

{{#each blog.recent_posts}}

{{url}}

{{getImage thumbnail 'gallery_size'}}

{{thumbnail.alt}}

{{title}}

{{summary}}

{{/each}}
```

But is there any other blog data I can pull, and have it on any page??

Can I specify {{thumbnail.alt}} and if so where?

Can I change the number of characters pulled in {{summary}}

Ideally can I pull blog tags somehow on the home page?

I need something, anything I can hide a list of urls in so I can write some javascript to categorize this blog and have certain blog articles appear on certain pages...

Answer (score 1):

There's loads more data available. Check out the stencil documentation and

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/other-objects-and-properties-overview#other-objects_blog

It looks like you already have the thumbnail alt in there, but here's some more:

limit summary

{{ellipsis summary 75}}

blog tags

```
      {{#each tags}}

        <li class="tag">

          <a href="{{url}}">#{{name}}</a>

        </li>

      {{/each}}
```

I think you might be needing to check out 'filter' under handlebar help reference to return just certain blogs / categories though.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/handlebars-helpers-reference

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to set the image alt tag. It will simply return the title of the post. I will ask the BigCommerce team to look into potentially setting up a way to specify the alt text.

If you need additional control over the blog data, your best bet would be to make AJAX calls to the frontend API to get the data, then manipulate it using JavaScript. You can check out this article I wrote on displaying only posts that are tagged with "featured": https://medium.com/bigcommerce-developer-blog/how-to-feature-a-blog-post-in-bigcommerce-f67d15d36597

The main power comes from this function:

```
api.getPage('/blog/', options, (error, response) => {})
```